# Objective C ^ Declare block in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, nsdictionary

I have following code part of Philips Hue SDK in Objective C (imported with bridging header)

```
[self.bridgeSearch startSearchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *bridgesFound) {

     // do something

}];
```

And I don't no, how to access this function in Swift.

I tried following (suggestion of Xcode 6)

```
    self.bridgeSearch?.startSearchWithCompletionHandler({ (bridgesFound:NSDictionary) -> Void in

        // do something

    })
```

But compiler brings following error:

'[NSObject : AnyObject]!' is not a subtype of 'NSDictionary'

Comment: Try changing the closure parameter into an optional: `bridgesFound: NSDictionary?` or `bridgesFound: NSDictionary!`

Comment: Already tried, but not worked

Comment: Or `bridgesFound:[NSObject : AnyObject]!`

Comment: This worked for me: self.bridgeSearch?.startSearchWithCompletionHandler({ bridgesFound in
            // do something
        })